# Is there any vulnerability if I encrypt disk with LUKS and TPM without specifying pcr_ids?

Tags: luks, tpm

According to many tutorials on the internet, the process of adding a TPM-stored key to LUKS is to run `clevis luks bind -d /dev/sda1 tpm2 '{"pcr_ids": "7"}'`, but I received the following error:

```
ERROR: pcr-input-file filesize does not match pcr set-list
ERROR: Could not build pcr policy
ERROR: Unable to run tpm2_createpolicy
Invalid input!
```

So I removed pcr_ids and the command becomes `clevis luks bind -d /dev/sda1 tpm2 '{}'`. This works well. A "passphrase" is added to a slot and adding the disk to /etc/crypttab (with tpm2-device=auto) enables the disk to be decrypted automatically at boot.

I am not sure whether it is secure enough. Is there any vulnerability with this practice?

P.S. I am using AMD 5950X (and its ftpm) on a MSI X570A-PRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding TPM-sealed<sup>1</sup> data to PCRs is used to impose specific requirements on the system state. Without any (useful) PCRs in the policy, the data (i.e. the LUKS key) can be unsealed from any OS and any environment.

So although the data is still bound to the same *machine*, it is not protected against someone booting up a Linux LiveCD on that machine and manually unsealing the LUKS key via `tpm2_load`; nor against someone quickly editing your /boot/initrd to make it print the unsealed key on screen; nor against someone adding `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel command line and bypassing the OS login password that way.

PCR7 is usually recommended as it binds to the Secure Boot state (e.g. with BitLocker it limits unsealing the key to when a Microsoft-signed Windows kernel is loaded, not when a third-party certificate is used), although I'm not sure if that is quite enough for Linux with Shim-based Secure Boot support. Other options are either too specific and fragile (e.g. PCR4) or not specific enough (e.g. PCR4).

"tpm2-device=auto" doesn't look like it's for Clevis, though – it's for the tpm2 plugin provided by systemd-cryptsetup, which I think is incompatible with Clevis in the way it stores LUKS metadata. The corresponding command is `systemd-cryptenroll --tpm2-pcrs=7 /dev/sda1`.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Not TPM-stored, as the TPM returns the encrypted data back to the OS for storage.*

Comment: I guess the reason why sealing key with pcr 7 fails can be that secure boot is not enabled (signing all modules for proxmox ve is quite complex). Is there any suggestion using TPM to encrypt hard drive without secure boot enabled?

Comment: It is possible to rely on PCR 4 or 4+11 securely, but not by default – it takes additional work that needs to be done after every kernel upgrade or every initramfs rebuild (e.g. hooked into the package manager as a "post-update" thing). Specifically, PCR 4 records exact hashes of everything that EFI executes, you'd need to make sure the kernel and initramfs are included in it (plus the kernel command line which might go to PCR 11 or such) as well as re-seal the keys after *every* kernel upgrade. I've done so for systemd-boot+mkinitcpio, but don't have a step-by-step guide for GRUB+Dracut.

Comment: (Does Proxmox really use out-of-tree kernel modules? I thought the whole point was that it relied on the already built-in KVM support.)

Comment: Thanks! Your tpm_futurepcr is convenient and it works for grub with general initrd. It seems like pcrvalues.bin and policy.bin can be removed after tpm2_createpolicy, doesn't it? BTW, all modules of proxmox (as well as the kernel itself) are not signed, and I will need to sign nvme, realtek, nf_conntrack, etc. one by one.

Comment: If proxmox doesn't enable module signing at kernel build time, then AFAIK the resulting kernel shouldn't be requiring module signature either (even in Secure Boot mode), but either way you can just mass-sign them all – `find /lib/modules -name '*.ko' -exec ...` I'm not sure if the kernel supports loading custom trusted module-signing certificates though...

Comment: The policy.bin file can be removed at the very end, but calling `tpm2_createpolicy` isn't the final step – you actually need to use that policy as part of the LUKS key sealing process, e.g. by giving the policy to `tpm2_create` (for example, https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/main/system/luks2-tpm-systemd-reseal#L64 creates LUKS2 "tokens" compatible with systemd-cryptenroll, and https://paste.rs/xQu does kinda the same for an older mkinitcpio-tpm2 plugin).